# pick random element from 2d array equally likely

Tags: random, multidimensional-array

I have two dimension array that each 1 layer of elements has different size of array. For example, its something like

```
 first element  1  9
 second element 7
 third element  10 3  2
 fourth element 6  92 14 73
```

**How to pick an element from this 2d array equally likely?** The one obvious way to pick random element from 2d is generate random numbers and pick like row of array[first random] and generate second based on size of that element, but it doesn't pick an element equally likely (e.g second element contains 1 element which will have more probabilities than others 25% chance where other elements have less than 25%). This approach will work if all elements in first layer have same size of array but not this case. I also consider performance (array is quite big enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generate a random number from 1 to your entire element count (10 in your example).  Then loop through the first level of your array, keeping track of how many elements you've encountered so far.

i.e. in psuedo:

```
randomNumber = rand(1,10)
soFar = 0
for(i=0, i<topLevel.size, i++)
  if ((soFar + topLevel[i].size) > randomNumber)
    return topLevel[i][randomNumber - soFar]
  else
    soFar += topLevel[i].size
```

Comment: your psuedo code doesn't quite generate randomness, in fact. If first element of toplevel contains only 1 element, your code most likely pick first element since your if statement's condition (1 < randomnumber between 1 to 10) is true all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just normalize it into a 1D array?

Visually, if your 2D array looks like this:

```
0:  X X
1:  X
2:  X X X
3:  X X X X
```

Think of it like this:

```
0: (X X) (X) (X X X) (X X X X)
```

Parentheses just added for clarity, to show that each row of the original is being concatenated into one long row.

Now you just have to get a single random number from 0 to N-1, where N is the total number of 'X's in the diagram.

Of course, in order to actually *access* the chosen random element, you will have to skip through the 2D array appropriately (see [Jeff Swensen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734576/pick-random-element-from-2d-array-equaly-likey/5734661#5734661)).

Answer (score 0):

Treat the collection as a long 1-dimensional array.  Generate a random number between 0 and the length -1 of that array.

So, in your example, you have 10 total items (0-9 assuming 0-based indexing).  Now each item has an equal chance of being selected.

You'll either have to calculate the total items or maintain it as you add/subtract items.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random number from `0` to (exclusive) `(#layer1+#layer2+#layer3+#layer4)`, where the `#` operator means "number of elements". Now if the random number is between `0` and `#layer1` return `layer1[randomnumber]`. Etcetera.

So basicly,  treat the array as one long one-dimension array.

Comment: your approach has problem, that is, what if two layers have same size of array?

Comment: @Ha-eun Chung: Eehm, could you rephrase that?

Comment: so what if #layer 1 and #layer 2 has same size of array. You generate random number that is between 0 and #layer1, how could you determine to pick layer since layer1 and layer2 has same size of array.

Comment: Ha-eun Chung: You check between `0` and `#layer1`, then between `#layer1` and `#layer2`, etc :)